# how to dynamically update a Prometheus collector's label set at runtime?

Tags: prometheus

Say I have a Prometheus collector whose label set is ['business'], I need to update the collector so its new label set will be ['business','country'], right now it's not possible as long as I am using the client-go library. Is there any suggestion for such kind of usage?

I tried to re-register the collector using:

```
    newCollector := prometheus.NewGaugeVec(prometheus.GaugeOpts{
                Name: name,
                Help: help,
            }, ['business','country'])

       registry.UnRegister(theOldCollector)
       registry.Register(newCollector)
```

However, this leads to a panic: `panic: a previously registered descriptor with the same fully-qualified name as Desc`, even though I have seemingly unregistered the old collector.